# How to lockScreen and unlockScreen remotely in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, lockscreen

is there any API can do it?I want to lock screen and unlock it remotely in the setting time,without password,just make the screen black and can make it bright again,the case like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES]
```

when we get the phone near our ears the screen closes,and far bright again,i just want to controll the screen lock and unlock remotely.